# Crystal report not remembering the password for ODBC(RDO) connection

Tags: crystal-reports

We have some crystal reports and we want to migrate these reports to a different server.
For that we need to change the connection server.When we change the Connection Server from previous(ODBC RDO) to new Server(ODBC RDO) using **set datasource Location** option in field Explorer. Connection changes successfully, and Report works fine in visual studio But when we close the Report and again open that report fron solution explorer it Again asks for Server password.
Rpt file Not able to remember password.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify the report and then save it. If this doesn't work check if this tool will work for you:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CRDataSource.aspx